# Set slide to older state with a reset button

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The question: How to go about storing a PowerPoint slide in VBA such that when the reset button is hit the slide will go back to its original state?

What I have tried:

```
Public default_state As Slide

Sub abc()
default_state = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
...
wonderful code
...
End Sub

Sub xyz()
ActivePresentation.Slides(1) = default_state
End Sub
```

Here the xyz sub is run when the reset button is pressed. I learned rather quickly that the contained assignment is not supported.

Comment: Make a copy of the slide?

Comment: It all needs to stay as one slide. Basically the slide gets info from an excel file, and I want the reset button to take the slide back to its state before it got data from excel. If you are suggesting that I make a copy of the slide and then set this slide to that, I am saying I do not know how to do this

Comment: In other words, it needs to be done programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for starters:

```
Sub MakeDefaultSlide()

    Dim oDefaultSlide As Slide

    ' Dupe the slide
    Set oDefaultSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate(1)

    ' Tag the presentation with the slide's index so we can find it later
    ' then hide the slide
    With oDefaultSlide
        ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "DefaultSlideIndex", CStr(oDefaultSlide.SlideIndex)
        .SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True
    End With
    ' Note that you could also tag the presentation with the original slide's
    ' SlideIndex in case you're not working with slide 1

End Sub

Sub RestoreDefaultSlide()

    With ActivePresentation
        'Delete the modified slide
        .Slides(1).Delete

        ' And move the default slide back into its place
        With .Slides(CLng(.Tags("DefaultSlideIndex")) - 1)
            .MoveTo (1)
            .SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```